# knockoutjs data-bind not working in inner loop

Tags: loops, foreach, knockout.js, nested-loops, knockout-mvc

**Case 1:** -- **Working**

**HTML**

```
Test::<span data-bind="text: $parent.testText"></span>
<button  data-bind="click: $parent.testbtn"></button>
```

**JS**

```
numberOfClicks : ko.observable(0),
incrementClickCounter : function() {
 alert('click called..');
 var previousCount = this.numberOfClicks();
 this.numberOfClicks("Testtttt....");
}
```

**Case 2:** -- **Working**

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: loop1(), as: 'styleColor'} -->
 Test::<span data-bind="text: $parent.testText"></span>
 <button  data-bind="click: $parent.testbtn"></button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

**Case 3:** -- **Not working**

**HTML**

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: loop1(), as: 'styleColor'} -->
 <div class="standard-color" data-bind="foreach: $parent.loop2()">                    
     Test::<span data-bind="text: $parent.testText"></span>
     <button  data-bind="click: $parent.testbtn"></button>
 </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

When I click on button, js function not calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to nest multiple `foreach` loops, even if they get their data from a parent layer. You have to realize that each of those loops creates a new layer in the binding context. Getting the right `$parent` can become a tricky exercise...

My advice is to move some of the looping logic to your viewmodel.

Here's an example that does a nested loop:

```js
(function() {
  const colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue"];
  const styles = ["glossy", "matte"];

  const selectedColor = ko.observable("red");
  const selectedStyle = ko.observable("glossy");

  const select = (color, style) => {
    selectedColor(color);
    selectedStyle(style);
  }

  ko.applyBindings(
    { colors, styles, selectedColor, selectedStyle, select }
  );
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h1>Your selection: <span data-bind="text: selectedColor"></span>, <span data-bind="text: selectedStyle"></span></h1>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: colors, as: 'color' }">
  <!-- ko foreach: { data: $parent.styles, as: 'style' } -->
  <li data-bind="
    click: $parents[1].select.bind(null, color, style),
    text: color + ', ' + style"></li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Here's an example that moves some logic to JS:

```js
(function() {
  const colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue"];
  const styles = ["glossy", "matte"];

  const options = colors.flatMap(color =>
    styles.map(style => ({ color, style, label: `${color}, ${style}` }))
  )

  const selectedOption = ko.observable(options[0]);

  ko.applyBindings(
    { options, selectedOption }
  );
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h1 data-bind="with: selectedOption">
  Your selection: <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
</h1>

<ul data-bind="foreach: options">
  <li data-bind="
    click: $parent.selectedOption,
    text: label"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69554125/knockout-js-for-each-loop-issue-with-custom-array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568465/onclick-bind-image-using-knockout-js