# knockout js , for each loop issue with custom array

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm trying to get color_name from colors.standard.

I have try as given below html but both are showing same array.

**HTML** - not working

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: doorColorList, as: 'column' }">
    
    <span class="style-name" data-bind="text: name"></span>
        
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: column.colors.standard, as: 'section' }">
        
            <p data-bind="text:console.log(section)"></p> 
      
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML** Not Working

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: doorColorList, as: 'column' }">
        
    <span class="style-name" data-bind="text: name"></span>
        
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: column.colors.standard, as: 'section' }">
        <div data-bind="foreach: { data: section, as: 'colorsection' }">
      
            <p data-bind="text:console.log(colorsection)"></p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Console**
JS Array:

```
{
    "style_id": "3",
    "name": "Rockford",
    "colors": {
        "standard": {
            "27": {
                "style_id": "3",
                "color_id": "27",
                "color_name": "White",
                "color_group": "1",
                "sort_order": "2",
                "defaultStyleId": "4"
            },
            "28": {
                "style_id": "3",
                "color_id": "28",
                "color_name": "Cloud White",
                "color_group": "1",
                "sort_order": "1",
                "defaultStyleId": "4"
            }
        },
        "doorcolor": {
            "18": {
                "style_id": "3",
                "cabinet_line_id": "1",
                "door_id": "1",
                "meta_keywords": null,
                "meta_description": null,
                "price_id": "3",
                "color_id": "18",
                "color_name": "Carbon",
                "color_group": "2",
                "sort_order": "8"
            }
        },
       }
    }
}
```

How can i get **color_name** from **colors.standard?**

for now it's showing array, if i add one more foreach loop it's still giving array.

Comment: `colors.standard` is an object, not an array. Knockout's `foreach` doesn't know how to iterate objects. You can use `data: Object.values(column.colors.standard)` to loop over the object's values (which is probably what you want).

Comment: Thanks, It's working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout's `foreach` needs an [*iterable*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#built-in_iterables) to be able to repeat the template you give it and render its UI.

Javascript objects are not iterable by default. Your `colors.standard` property holds an object, so knockout does not know how to loop it.

In this particular case, you probably want to loop over the *values* of your object. To get an array of the object's values, you can use:

`data: Object.values(column.colors.standard)`

Other strategies could be:

- Loop over an object's *keys* by using `Object.keys`
- Loop over an object's *entries* (`[key, value]` pairs) by using `Object.entries`

Note that the order of the values/keys/entries typically relies on the order in which they were defined. Unlike arrays, an object doesn't let you easily re-order. That's why you often see a `.sort` chained behind `Object.values`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568465/onclick-bind-image-using-knockout-js