# Onclick bind image using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I want to show image from allDoorColorStandard.

**HTML:**

Onclick "**color-data**" div , i want to update image.
In alert i'm getting image URL, now need to bind in image tag.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: doorColorList, as: 'doorStyleType' }">
    
                <img class="mappimg" width="45" height="45" alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: $parent.mappingImage}" if="$parent.mappingImage">

   
   <div data-bind="foreach: { data: Object.values(doorStyleType.colors.standard) , as: 'allDoorColorStandard' }">  
        <div class="color-data" data-bind="click: $parents[1].selectColor">      
         
            <span class="style-name" data-bind="text: allDoorColorStandard.color_name"></span>
        </div>      
    </div>
    
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
selectColor: function (styleColor,color) {
  alert('kkkk'+styleColor.mapping_image);
  self.mappingImage(styleColor.mapping_image);
},
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unwrap `mappingImage`:

```
<img class="mappimg" width="45" height="45" alt="" data-bind="attr: {src: $parent.mappingImage()}, if:$parent.mappingImage">
```

Comment: It's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any error messages at all? It is a bit difficult to see without seeing the structure of your data/vm. Does the property `mappingImage` belong to the `doorColorList` array?